# Почему не происходит запуск кода?

Tags: javascript, объекты, операторы

Что значит эта ошибка?

```js
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
};
function func(a, ...b) {
    console.log(a, b);
};
func(...obj); //Uncaught TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

Comment: [TypeError: 'x' is not iterable (Тип ошибки 'x' не является итерационным)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для использования spread при вызове функции, передаваемый объект должен быть итерируемым (иметь метод `Symbol.iterator` возвращающий итератор).

В данном случае передается обычный объект, у которого данного метода нет.

Для решения можно либо использовать массив, либо объявить недостающий метод:

```js
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3,
    [Symbol.iterator]: function*(){
      for(const entry of Object.values(this)){
        yield entry;
      }
    }
};
let arr = [1,2,3];
function func(a, ...b) {
    console.log(a, b);
};
func(...obj); 
func(...arr);
```

Comment: … но делать так не нужно потому что порядок получившихся значений может быть неожиданным…

Comment: @AlexeyTen, фактически порядок можно самому задать